# Movimiento regular en animación css

Tags: html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                alert(($("#marcas").css('left')));
        })  
$(window).scroll(function(){
 var margin = $("#marcas").css('left'); 

 if (margin == '0px') {
  $("#marcas").addClass('moving1');
 }
 if ( margin == '-200px') {
  $("#marcas").addClass('moving2');
 }
 if ($("#marcas").css('left') == '-400px') {
  $("#marcas").addClass('moving3');
 }
 if ($("#marcas").css('left') == '-600px') {
  $("#marcas").addClass('moving4');
 }
 if ($("#marcas").css('left') == '-800px') {
  $("#marcas").addClass('moving5');
 }
 if ($("#marcas").css('left') == '-1000px') {
  $("#marcas").addClass('moving6');
 }
 if ($("#marcas").css('left') == '-1200px') {
  $("#marcas").addClass('moving7');
 }
 else {
  alert(none);
 }

});

$.fn.scrollEnd = function(callback, timeout) {          
  $(this).scroll(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('scrollTimeout')) {
      clearTimeout($this.data('scrollTimeout'));
    }
    $this.data('scrollTimeout', setTimeout(callback,timeout));
  });
};

// how to call it (with a 1000ms timeout):
$(window).scrollEnd(function(){
   al 
}, 500000);
```

```css
body{margin:0;height:10000px;}
  #marcas{ position:fixed; left:0px; width:4000px;overflow: hidden; }
  .moving1{
 animation-name: moving1;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 animation-timing-function: linear;
 }
  .moving2{
 animation-name: moving2;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
 }
   .moving3{
 animation-name: moving3;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
 }
    .moving4{
 animation-name: moving4;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
 }
     .moving5{
 animation-name: moving5;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
 }
       .moving6{
 animation-name: moving6;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
 }
       .moving7{
 animation-name: moving7;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
 }
.verde{width:800px; height:100vh; background:green; display:inline-block; left:0;}
.rojo{width:800px; height:100vh; background:red;display:inline-block;  }
@-webkit-keyframes moving1 {
  0%   { translateX(0px); }
  100% { translateX(200px); }
}
@-moz-keyframes moving1 {
  0%   { translateX(0px); }
  100% { translateX(200px); }
}
@-o-keyframes moving1 {
  0%   { translateX(0px); }
  100% { translateX(200px); }
}
@keyframes moving1 {
  0%   { translateX(0px); }
  100% { translateX(200px); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moving2{
  0% { left: -200px; }
  100% { left: -400px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes moving2 {
  0% { left: -200px; }
  100% { left: -400px; }
}
@-o-keyframes moving2 {
  0% { left: -200px; }
  100% { left: -400px; }
}
@keyframes moving2 {
  0% { left: -200px; }
  100% { left: -400px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moving3{
  0%   { left: -400px; }
  100% { left: -600px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes moving3 {
  0%   { left: -400px; }
  100% { left: -600px; }
}
@-o-keyframes moving3 {
  0%   { left: -400px; }
  100% { left: -600px; }
}
@keyframes moving3 {
  0%   { left: -400px; }
  100% { left: -600px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moving4{
  0%   { left: -600px; }
  100% { left: -800px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes moving4 {
  0%   { left: -600px; }
  100% { left: -800px; }
}
@-o-keyframes moving4 {
  0%   { left: -600px; }
  100% { left: -800px; }
}
@keyframes moving4 {
  0%   { left: -600px; }
  100% { left: -800px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moving5{
  0%   { left: -800px; }
  100% { left: -1000px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes moving5{
  0%   { left: -800px; }
  100% { left: -1000px; }
}
@-o-keyframes moving5{
  0%   { left: -800px; }
  100% { left: -1000px; }
}
@keyframes moving5{
  0%   { left: -800px; }
  100% { left: -1000px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moving6{
  0%   { left: -1000px; }
  100% { left: -1200px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes moving6{
  0%   { left: -1000px; }
  100% { left: -1200px; }
}
@-o-keyframes moving6{
  0%   { left: -1000px; }
  100% { left: -1200px; }
}
@keyframes moving6{
  0%   { left: -1000px; }
  100% { left: -1200px; }
}
@-webkit-keyframes moving7{
  0%   { left: -1200px; }
  100% { left: -1400px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes moving7{
  0%   { left: -1200px; }
  100% { left: -1400px; }
}
@-o-keyframes moving7{
  0%   { left: -1200px; }
  100% { left: -1400px; }
}
@keyframes moving7{
  0%   { left: -1200px; }
  100% { left: -1400px; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="marcas" >
<div class="verde">
</div><div class="rojo">
</div><div class="verde">
</div><div class="rojo">
</div><div class="verde">
</div>
</div>
```

¿Hay alguna manera de hacer que la velocidad de la animación sea regular? Por ejemplo, si un div se mueve 20px en 2 segundos, que se mueva a 10px/seg y no en esa curva de 5px/seg a 15px/seg.
Cómo se haría para empezar la animación desde la situación en la que se encuentra cuando, por ejemplo, añadimos una clase?

Comment: Hola @IvanSoler, ¿Te refieres a `keyframes` o a `transition`?

Comment: hola @MitsuGami keyframes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por supuesto. Supongamos que tienes un div y quieres que se mueva de 0 a 400px de forma **lineal** (sin ninguna variación entre la velocidad entre la inicial o final), basta con especificar la propiedad `animation-timing-function` con el valor `linear`, como si de una transición se tratara.

```
.animate {
    animation-name: move;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
    0% {  translateX(0px); }
    33.333% { translateX(200px); }
    66.666% { translateX(400px); }
}
```

Comment: Ostras muchas gracias ! Una cosa ya que estamos, la añado ahora en un edit a la pregunta general.. cómo sería para empezar la animación desde el punto en el que está y no uno prefijado? Gracias !

Comment: Con el `0% { translateX(0px); }` indico que la animación empezará en donde se encuentra el elemento en la pantalla.

Comment: Perdona Mitsu pero no funciona para mí puesto que se trata de un div fijo el que estoy moviendo y debo hacerlo con 0% { left:0px } 0%{left:-200px} se te ocurre alguna solución?

Comment: Ten en cuenta que para elementos **fijos** no puedes usar `left`, si no en su lugar `translate`. Si usas `left` se asume que el elemento tiene un `position: absolute;`. Si lo tienes así, digamos con un `left:  300px;` entonces la animación debe empezar también con `left: 300px;`.

Comment: He de decirte que con translate no funciona, de todas formas hago un edit para que veas el ejemplo en funcionamiento ya que estamos y así lo entenderás mejor.